# stringstrings replacement for XeTeX?

Tags: xetex, fontspec, strings

To construct a lower-case filename out of the mixed-case argument given to a command, I used `stringstrings` in LaTeX.

Now I switched to XeTeX and it seems the `fontspec`-package has some interference with `stringstrings`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,stringstrings}
\begin{document}
  \caselower[q]{AbC}\thestring
\end{document}
```

Produces an error message only when `fontspec` is used:

```
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.4 \thestring
```

Just using `\lowercase` for display won't work, because I need to use it like

```
\edef{\filename}{stuff/\thestring.tex}
\input{\filename}
```

(there seems to be a similar clash between `stringstrings` and `polyglossia`)

So: what would be other string manipulation packages for LaTeX and XeTeX (`coolstr` is mentioned, but only supports substring operations I don't need)? Or is there a fix by redefining something?

Comment: Your example works on my machine with current TeX Live.

Comment: Then my Ubuntu version of TeX Live is outdated… (looks like they have a reputation for lagging horribly behind with TeX versions) Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in TeX Live 2010, thx Philipp.